# Debian Jessie, DHClient run string?

Tags: networking, dhcp, debian-jessie

Using Debian Jessie (on a Seagate Dockstar), it has DHclient for it's dhcp client. The damn thing is being started with:

> dhclient -v -pf /run/dhclient.eth1.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth1.leases eth1

on all interfaces.

I need to disable the verbose mode, but can't find the config file that launches this when an interface goes up.

What launches dhclient on automatic interface enabling?

Comment: Of course I've already gone grepping in /etc and can't find anything.

Comment: /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf does not exist? at min there should be a shell script /sbin/dhclient-script

Comment: Neither of which I see anything regarding verbose or building the string for launching dhclient with the pid or leases.

Comment: how about /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-eth0.conf

Comment: @DRP doesn't exist, and grep doesn't find pid or dhclient anywhere in /var/lib

Comment: @DRP found my answer. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to change it. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14743683/1498667 I looked for the Jessie version of ifupdown sources, and per the change log:

> ifupdown (0.6.8+nmu3) unstable; urgency=low
>
> - Non-maintainer upload. (with maintainer's consent)
> - Correctly make the modification in 0.6.8+nmu2
> - Also adjust the way /sbin/dhclient is killed to be comparable to how
>     /sbin/dhclient is stopped
> - **Invoke dhclient with -v to maintain equivalent verbosity to dhclient3**
> - Conflict with dhcp-client v2

This is hard coded into ifupdown, and I would have to patch, compile, and replace to fix this "improvement". Alternatively, I need to see if BusyBox syslogd can filter this out. Yay.